# Не работает поиск по нажатию на кнопку поиска мышью

Tags: jquery, opencart, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Не работает поиск по нажатию на кнопку поиска мышью. При нажатии кнопки Enter все ОК.
Движок Opencart
При нажатии Enter получается переход на такой адрес: http://www.site.ru/index.php?route=product/search&search=30802
А при нажатии мышью на такой: http://www.site.ru/index.php?route=product/search
То есть почему-то не передается параметр поиска &search=30802.

Comment: Верстку формы в студию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема была в том, что в коде страницы присутствовало 2 формы поиска. Не рабочая выше той, что есть на сайте. 
Поэтому при клике бралось пустое значение из ненужной формы.